# AAD lacks permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

Currently working on deploying an older internal company site to Azure AD, and the final hurdle is replacing LDAP integration with AAD (using the ActiveDirectoryClient class for this).

The following code works in the new site that will be replacing the old one, but fails in the older site:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = General.GetADClient();
User currentUser = adClient.Users.Where(u => u.UserPrincipalName == Page.User.Identity.Name).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result as User;
```

...which produces the following error:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

As far as I can tell, both web apps have nigh-identical settings. The app manifests in the AAD app registration are also similarly identical.

So my question specifically: does anybody have any idea what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the post is filtering the Azure AD users collection using Azure AD Graph REST. To query the uses collection, if you were using the delegated permission, we can grant the `Users.ReadBasic.All` permission to the app.

And for narrow down this issue, we can also using the Fiddler to track the request and then parse the token [here](https://jwt.io/) to see whether there are the sufficient privileges. More detail about the permission and scopes about the Azure AD Graph, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).

If you still have the problem, please post the payload data in the token.